# Python Как получить доступ к api.telegram.org используя tor?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, tor

Использую следующий код на python, по первому запросу возвращается возвращается измененный адрес, а второй запрос возвращает ошибку. Я так понимаю, что прокси не работает в полной мере, что с этим делать?

```
import requests 
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',
    'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'
}

url = "https://api.telegram.org/"
url_ip = "http://httpbin.org/ip"

def get_updates_json(request):  
    response = requests.get(request, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
    return response

print(get_updates_json(url_ip).text)
print(get_updates_json(url).text)
```

Сама ошибка

> SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1051)')))

Comment: Если проблема еще актуальна - я бы для начала попробовал сменить цепочку TOR, и второе - проверил бы корректность настройки ssl на машине.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150'
}
```

Comment: А чем `socks5` отличается от `socks5h`?

Comment: socks5h: // и socks4a: // означают, что имя хоста разрешается сервером SOCKS.         
socks5: // и socks4: // означают, что имя хоста разрешается только локально

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :)